# Spherical Harmonics & Beltrami operator

Tags: geometry, eigenfunctions

I don't know if I can ask this question here, but there's a question on MO for which I have a good interest. The problem is I don't think I have competencies to do it. On the page [The spherical harmonics are the EIGENVECTORS of Beltrami operator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/242749/the-spherical-harmonics-are-the-eigenvectors-of-beltrami-operator), Paul Siegel has answered this question. Could anyone be able to develop in details his answer?

> **Interest question :** Is every eigenfunction of the Laplacian a spherical harmonic?

**Questions :** ($1$) Why if $H$ is dense in $L^2 (\mathbb{S}^2)$, then that answer respond the main question?

($2$) Why every polynomial of $\mathbb{S}^2$ is a sum of homogeneous polynomial?

($3$) Why every homogeneous polynomial is a sum of harmonic polynomial?

($4$) Why a spherical harmonic is in fact an harmonic polynomial restricted to $\mathbb{S}^2$? I have tried with the spherical harmonic $u(x,y,z)=xyz$ and use this spherical coordinates, but it seems don't respect the homogeneous property.

Thanks!

Comment: $L^2(S^2)$ means the Hilbert space on the surface of the sphere, with the usual inner product (the one that makes the sphere symmetric), and he explains how we easily know that all the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian (unbounded) operator $\Delta : L^2(S^2) \to L^2(S^2)$ are spherical harmonics

Comment: for (3) see lemma 1.4 $\to$ 1.8 in http://www.axler.net/HarmonicPolynomials.pdf proving that homogeneous polynomials can be written as sum of harmonic polynomials. (2) is obvious once you know what homogeneous polynomials are, the only one problem I have is with (4), I guess the fact that the spherical harmonics by definition fulfill $\Delta \psi + \lambda \psi = 0$ and the fact  they are of the form $C P_l^m( \cos \theta) e^{i m \varphi}$ are important, but I'm not sure of the argument