# Stone-Weierstrass theorem of $\mathbb{S}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Someone told me that every continuous function on $\mathbb{S}^2$ could be expressed as a uniform limit of restrictions to $\mathbb{S}^2$ of polynomials. Does this result come from the Stone-Weierstrass theorem? Could anyone be able to explain to me what it means formally?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just not to worry that the restriction of polynomials will satisfy the hypotheses of Stone-Weierstrass, let's use Tietze's theorem to extend our function from $S^2$ to the cube. Now we can apply Stone-Weierstrass to this continuous extended function, approximate it by polynomials, and restrict them.

Comment: we can consider instead $F(r, \theta,\varphi) = r \, G(\theta,\varphi)$  where $G(\theta,\varphi)$ is the function on the sphere we'd like to approximate, and  $F$ is a continuous function on the ball $\|x\| = r < R$ ?

Comment: and see his other question which is interesting http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836490/spherical-harmonics-beltrami-operator#1836490